# java.lang.IllegalStateException: opening Dialog after changing screen orientation

Tags: android, android-fragments

I get a "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState" when I change screen the orientation and I click on Image and try to open a dialog. I have seen that superclass DialogFragment.show() does a TransactionManager.commit() and then crashes. It only happens when I change the orientation.
I don't know how to avoid this exception.
The code:

```
public class CustomView extends LinearLayout {
   ....
   final ImageView pic=(ImageView)  v.findViewById(R.id.mypic);  
   student_pic.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final MyDialog     
                   picker=MyDialog.newInstance(CustomView.this);
            picker.show(getContext());

        }
    });  
}
```

MyDialog.java:

```
public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment {
   public static MyDialog newInstance(View f) {
        MyDialog frag = new MyDialog();
        return frag;
    }
   .....
   public void show(Context context)
   {   
       FragmentManager fm=((Activity)context).getFragmentManager();     
       show(fm, "MyDialog"); // The superclass show() does a FragmentManager.commit() and crash
   }
}
```

stacktrace:

```
10-29 00:05:07.452      
 621-621/com.myapp.example E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION:     main
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1280)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1291)
    at android.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:548)
    at android.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:532)
    at android.app.DialogFragment.show(DialogFragment.java:230)
    at com.myapp.table.MyDialog.show(MyDialog.java:234)
    at com.myapp.table.MyDialog.show(MyDialog.java:224)
    at com.myapp.table.MyDialog.show(MyDialog.java:217)
    at   com.myapp.table.views.MyCustomView$2$1$1.run(MyCustomView.java:152)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any help to avoid this exception?

Comment: post the stacktrace ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Instead of using a DialogFragment I use an AlertDialog to build dialogs.